# Instantiating a class in python with a variable in the Class

Tags: python, class, instantiation

```
class Neuralnetwork(data):

    def __init__(self, data):    
         self.data = data

    print(data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    Neuralnetwork(3)
```

I was expecting this to output the number 3, but I keep getting error: data not defined. But I thought I defined data when instantiating the class and passing it a value?

Comment: You should either declare the class: `class Neuralnetwork:` or `class Neuralnetwork(object)`, further, the print statement should be inside the `__init__` (fix the identation).

Answer (score 1):

It is true that you defined the `data` attribute when you instantiated, but the `print` line is executed at the class definition, before you instantiate. If you want to print the data, try `print(self.data)` *inside `__init__`*.

**Edit**: I did not notice at first that you declared your class as `class Neuralnetwork(data)`. That syntax means that you are creating a class that inherits from the `data` class. Since that class does not exist, you'll have an error. Just remove that and use `class Neuralnetwork` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I'm green to python, so I have another stupid question. I set up the print statement just to check to make sure that the data variable held something before I went further into creating additional methods and functions. How do I access the variable data?     That's why I was trying to print it, just testing how to get to the contents.

Comment: When you instantiate the class, assign a variable to it: `network = Neuralnetwork(3)`. You can then access the data as `network.data`. For example, `print(network.data)`.

Comment: Thanks making more sense to me!

Answer (score 0):

Your current system has Neuralnetwork inheriting from data. What you are currently trying to do is best done in the `__init__` method. You also really shouldn't do a print in the body of a class like this.

Python doesn't have the concept of private methods and function and as such everything can be accessed with dot notation. With that being said adding a `_` to the start of a function/method/field will tell the users of your class/library that it should be treated as though it was private.

```
class Neuralnetwork(object):

    def __init__(self, data):    
         self.data = data

    print(self.data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    nuralnetwork1 = Neuralnetwork(3)
    print(nuralnetwork1.data) # Prints the number 3 to the console
    nuralnetwork2 = Neuralnetwork(2)
    print(nuralnetwork2.data) # Prints the number 2 to the console
    print(nuralnetwork1.data + nuralnetwork2.data)  # Prints the number 5 to the console
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was really just trying to make sure that the data variable held the information I expected before I went on creating more functions and methods. How do I access that variable otherwise?